# Rewrite URL in .htaccess just cause 404 error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to learn how to rewrite URL in the .htaccess file. I have read some tutorials, but despite that I write as in the example code, nothing happens for me! I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here? I get a 404-code when I'm trying the code below.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /byggnader/1/ /?p=byggnad&id=1
```

This is just a test and I wonder if `/byggnader/` must be an existing file or just a name in the URL. I'm using a page controler design. So URL `/?p=byggnad&id=1` will open the `PSelectedBuilding.php` file inside the `index.php` file.

I preciate some feedback to be able to continue.

EDIT: Since it's not working despite the help below, I also add the code from the index.php file that handle the requests. Perhaps that could give a clue why!?

```
<?php
session_start();
// Allow only access to pagecontrollers through frontcontroller
$indexIsVisited = TRUE;

require_once('config.php'); 

// pagecontrol
$page = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : 'start';
switch($page) {
case 'start':           require_once('PIndex.php'); break;
case 'karta':           require_once('PMap.php'); break;
case 'byggnader':       require_once('PBuildings.php'); break;
case 'tips':            require_once('PTips.php'); break;
case 'visa-byggnad':    require_once('PHandleSessions.php'); break;
case 'byggnad':         require_once('PSelectedBuilding.php'); break;
case 'visa':            require_once('PSelectedBuilding.php'); break;
case 'visa2':           require_once('PHandleSessions.php'); break;
default:                require_once('PIndex.php'); break;
}
require_once("CreatePage.php"); // Call file that creates the page
?>
```

EDIT 2:

This works fine, but not when I'm using requests for some of the pages:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule bilder-byggnader-kopenhamn /?p=byggnader

RewriteRule karta-byggnader-kopenhamn /?p=karta

RewriteRule start /?p=start

RewriteRule tips /?p=tips
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: @elbuild To get cleaner URL like those in WordPress

Comment: Yes, I guessed that. But I was asking exaclty what you're trying to achieve with that rule (since it's incorrect but without understanding its purpose it's difficult to help you)

Comment: I would like the URL to be /byggnad/1/ instead of /?p=byggnad&id=1 I thougt the code in the .htaccess file would fix that, but I guess it's wrong. What is wrong?

Comment: The RewriteRule directive rewrite request matching the first item, to the second item...if your purpose is to  get  /byggnad/1/ as output you may have at least to change the order of your param. Besides the query string should be matched differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash from your rule. `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^byggnader/1/?$ /?p=byggnad&id=1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't working! When I type in /byggnader/1/ after the domain name, I just get this error: The requested URL /byggnad/1/ was not found on this server.

Comment: Are you sure .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: Yes I have asked the support

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not? Also tell me location of this .htaccess

Comment: It's enabled because I get an error message when I added some random text. I'm testing this on a localhost, so I guess I can't give you any location. It's getting late here, I have to continue tomorrow. Thanks so far!

Comment: I didn't ask for URL location but filesystem path

Comment: It's located in the root.

Comment: Is `/byggnader/` a directory? Does it also have .htaccess?

Comment: No 'byggnader' is not a directory. I made this little test with some simple URL and that worked!? RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule allan webb.php So when I use the URL .../allan the content of webb.php is displayed. But why isn't it working with the other URL?

Comment: Or should 'byggnader' be a directory with it's own .htaccess ?

Comment: No it doesn't need to be a directory and rule should work as is. It is one of the simplest rule I have suggested so don't know why it is not working on your localhost.

Comment: I have also tested on a host, but it's not working there either. Could the problem be in my index.php file? Preciate if you have some other ideas!? It's late here and I'm tired. I have to continue tomorrow and hopefully solve it!

Comment: I believe this is not being controlled by any CMS/PHP framework?

Comment: This is controlled by a PHP framework. Please look att my edit in the question above. Is there anything I can do in another way there to get this to work?

Comment: Can you create a file called `info.php` with this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and then open `http://domain.com/info.php` to check what is your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` value. Then make sure your .htaccess is placed in this `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` path.

Comment: Hi! I'm glad you are back! Sorry, but I get this message when I try: 404 Not Found

Comment: It worked also on the Internet host now. I have this .htaccess where I have all my other files. And since some of the rewrites are working, see edit 2 above, I guess I have placed it at the right place!?

Comment: I guess the problem is to handle to requests. The first request is handeld in the index.php file and the second is handled in the other file. But I guess this should not be a problem?

Comment: Hi again! I had some progress! I guess I made some misstakes and missed a subfolder! Sorry for that! Your example is almost working now, but the CSS style and images are not loading!? The HTML code is OK. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I accept this answer since it's working(not the CSS and images I will ask a new question for that)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. For css/js use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(\w+)&id=(\d+)  
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1/%2? [R=301, L]
```

The RewriteCond mathches the Query String (as per your wish) extracting two variables which you can reuse to build your redirection target in the rewrite rule directive. The final question mark tells Apache not to reappend existing QS. R=301 says that the redirection is permanent, L that this is the last rule to be processed.

You may have to play with the `index.php` part since you never put the `REQUEST_URI` part in your question.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! How can I "play with my index.php"?

Comment: I meant adapt the index.php part to your scenario (the previous part of your URL).